# How to accurately measure lorentz force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Assisting on a kid's school science project to demonstrate relationship between current & lorentz force. Demo works well. As we increase current we can see that the conductor passing through the magnetic field deviates ( swing type copper wire deflects towards right or left based on polarity) more and more. My question is: What is the best way ( other than visual indication) to measure the magnitude of the lorentz force ?

Comment: If either the wire or the magnet is on a pendulum you could use displacement of the pendulum. For extra credit you move the top of the pendulum to get wire centered again - this takes out nonlinearity in the magnetic field. As long as the pendulum is long the force will be proportional to displacement and can be calculated very accurately (longer pendulum = potentially greater accuracy)

Comment: Actually the wire is suspended like a pendulum ( 8 inches from top to the  magnetic field) and we are using a  protractor to measure the angle of deflection/displacement. What formula can we use to derive the lorentz force using the angle  ? Trying to come up with an alternate way to confirm what we already know via the formula F = BIL

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of your setup? For a pendulum with mass m at a distance $\ell$ from the pivot, the torque (force times distance) required for a displacement $\theta$ is $mg\ell\sin\theta \approx mg\ell\theta$. If you know the distance from the wire (point where force is generated) to the pivot you should be able to calculate the force.